# What do I do if some of my smoke alarms ac power doesn't work?

Tags: electrical, smoke-detectors

I have 5 smoke detectors in my home, 2 of them have the green ac power light on and are interconnected. Those 2 are on opposite sides of my home from each other but I have 3 on 1 side but those don't seem to have ac power and when the alarm goes off it doesn't interconnect with the rest. I made sure connection was plugged in properly but only 2 have the green light on

Comment: Did you check the voltage at the three not working?  Did they ever work? Did you change any wiring?

Comment: Have checked your breaker/fuse panel?

Comment: When home owners call me for electrical problems on things they installed, the “I am sure I hooked it up right” statement adds to the bill. The location in the home is not as important as the type of interconnect. What is the brand / model of the detectors? The interconnected ones I have installed are all on the same power source per zone / floor / pod , most home units are interconnected on the same circuit to prevent problems. With 1 bad splice just as with receptacles if interconnected in a chain it will be the last working detector or the first non working where the problem is.